# How to specific MSVC compiler version in cmake?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, llvm

I am trying to build `llvm` with MSVC 2017 as below:

```
git clone --branch llvmorg-9.0.1 https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -Thost=x64 ..\llvm -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<PATH_WHERE_LLVM_WILL_BE_INSTALLED>
cmake --build . --target INSTALL --config Release
```

but even I specific `-G "Visual Studio 15 2017"` and above is running in MSVC 2017 native prompt, it compiler version identified as MSVC 2019 as below:

```
>cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -Thost=x64 ..\llvm -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/lib/llvm"
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27045.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27045.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

Comment: This is correct. The MSVC version numbers are not related to whether it's VS 2017 or VS 2019. See https://walbourn.github.io/vs-2017-15-9-update/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=vs-2017 .

Comment: @Justin I see, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the console output that the Visual Studio 2017 compiler was indeed selected. There is no issue. Here are the lines in question:

```
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
```